# Android app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

After many attempts to use others network solutions , I feel despair .

I wil be  more then happy if someone could help me with this Problem!:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:       com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

My project run  perfectly until I tried to add new dependencies to my project 
org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:1.5.0, 
com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3 or 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1'- but withot success  - **Always get the same error.**

Each one I also tried to added in diffrent ways: as Module, Jar or Gradle dependencie of course - **Always get the same error.**

My Gradle Version: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

Android Studio: 1.5.1

SDK: 23

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.alfred.alfredapplication"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0'
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev40-1.21.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

/*compile files('libs/pdfbox-2.0.0.jar')*/

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

My AndroidManifest.xml include :

```
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
```

So what's the problem could be? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dont use multidex. Post your entire build.gradle.

Comment: I tried to use multidex just becouse someone else post it has a solution on network, even if I disabeld multidex I get the same error.

Comment: I update post with the entire bulid.gradle

Comment: 1. Try removing data binding 2. Try removing `multiDexEnabled true` 3. Try removing `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` 4. App compat should by the same version as design: `23.2.1` is the latest. After removing one by one, add them back in slowly.

Comment: I followed those steps but unfortunately get same error....

Comment: @Roi, tried your code. I have successfully built and connected all dependencies you have used but with minor changes. Added pdfbox-2.0.0.jar not pdfbox:1.5.0, downloaded mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-6.jar because com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3 causes error. Have you tried Cleaning and Rebuilding your project?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines under android { } in gradle file.

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
```

Comment: Problem solved! an old jar of mpandroidchart was in my "libs" folder

Comment: @RoiZlot Please delete your question or answer it yourself, so to avoid orphans and maybe help other people.